# I can't bind my table view to the content of NSArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to bind my tableview with an nsarray, I get data from a webservice and put it in my nsArray , the nsarray is filled successfully but still can't bind it with my cells in my tableview .

her where I create my cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ContactCell";
    ContactTableViewCell *cell = (ContactTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[ContactTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    Contact * contact = _contacts[indexPath.row];
    RAC(cell.fullNameLabel , text) = RACObserve(contact,firstName);
    RAC(cell.phoneNumberLabel , text) = RACObserve(contact,phoneNumber);
    UIImage *contactImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"contactPicture.png"];
    [cell.contactImage setImage:contactImage];

    return cell;
}
```

and that's my .h file where I have my NSArray

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa.h>
@interface ContactsTableView : UITableView <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray * contacts;
- (instancetype) init;
@end
```

I've add a method to check the content of the selected cell , and the nsarray at the same indexPath with this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    ContactTableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [selectedCell.contentView addSubview:selectedCell.fullNameLabel];
    NSLog(@"phoneLabel of cell %@", selectedCell.phoneNumberLabel.text);
    NSLog(@"phone number of array %@", ((Contact *) _contacts[indexPath.row]).phoneNumber);
}
```

and this is the output :

```
crm-app[49692:1409964] **phoneLabel of cell (null)**
2017-05-15 12:25:56.941 crm-app[49692:1409964] **phone number of array 0655443345**
```

Comment: add a breakpoint here Contact * contact = _contacts[indexPath.row]; and see if Contact has any values in it or not

Comment: It seems your IBOutlets are not connected , Recheck again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement `UITableView` delegates and datasource methods.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
//this will return number of cells in your array

return contacts.count;
}
```

Configuring a cell is usually dependent on the data you want to show, cellForRowAtIndexPath: is by far the most common place to do cell configuration.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell  = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_CELL_IDENTIFIER"];

// YOUR CODE HERE

    return cell;
}
```

you also have to reload your table after receiving data from server.

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

**NOTE:** Also check that you have set the tableview delegate and datasource.

Comment: thank you I forgot to add [myTableView reloadData]; after get my data that was my problem (y)

Answer (score 0):

To remove crash
first initialize the `NSMutableArray`  like

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
    }
```

Add `UITableViewDataSource` method in your controller

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section      {

     return [contacts count];
}
```